# Angular routing not working after running ng build at deployment

Tags: angular, build, routes, ng-build

not sure what im doing wrong here, im fairly new to Angular and im fumbling along somewhat with regards to routing.

I'm running Angular 12.2.0 and have setup routes on localhost. I'm just navigating between two pages at the moment to see how it works, its working fine locally.

For example on localhost I can browse from the root http://localhost:4200/ to http://localhost:4200/locations which works fine.

```
 const routes: Routes = [
  {path: '', component: HomeComponent},
  {path: 'locations', component: LocationsComponent}
];
```

When I run `ng build` to build the project, it runs fine and I can open the index.html fine

what I cannot do is navigate between the routes no more

Launching the build at `dist/angular-app/index.html` when I click on the locations link its wanting to link to `dist/angular-app/index.html/locations` which is blank even if I change the URL to `dist/angular-app/locations` that's also blank

Anyone point me in the right direction as to why its doing this?

Many thanks

Attaching my angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "angular-app": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {
        "@schematics/angular:component": {
          "style": "scss"
        },
        "@schematics/angular:application": {
          "strict": true
        }
      },
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/angular-app",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-app:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "angular-app:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "angular-app:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "main": "src/test.ts",
            "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "karmaConfig": "karma.conf.js",
            "inlineStyleLanguage": "scss",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.scss"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  },
  "defaultProject": "angular-app"
}
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Most likely it is because your webserver is actually trying to find a page corresponding to the URL. However, since an Angular app is a SPA the elements are injected into a page dynamically based on the url in your browser, therefore, when requesting a route the server returns 404 HTTP error.
This can be solved by using HashLocationStrategy from angular, which appends a # to your URL making it possible to navigate when the app is deployed.

Add this to your **app.module.ts** in the providers section.

```
providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]
```

Import:

```
import { HashLocationStrategy, LocationStrategy } from '@angular/common';
```

Edit:
Alternatively, If you are serving the application through Nginx or an Apache Server, you can add configuration entry in the config file to redirect all requests that have no matching file to /index.html.
More on that you can see https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Comment: Thank you Akmal, 

Adding

`providers: [{provide: LocationStrategy, useClass: HashLocationStrategy}]`

Did the trick, Yes the URL's are a ugly, but I guess I sort them out with .htaccess config as you linked to.

Thank you for taking the time to explain, I would have never worked that out

Comment: is there any other way that we can do without adding hash. I don't want to use hash

Comment: @SandeepBhaskar yes you can follow this https://angular.io/guide/deployment#server-configuration

Answer (score 2):

If **hosting with Nginx** change

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}
```

to

```
location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ /index.html;
}
```

This doesn't require HashLocationStrategy mentioned in Akmal's answer.

Comment: Can u specify in which file this should be changed?

Comment: @ShimiShimson either `nginx.conf` or `sites-available/example.com`

Answer (score 0):

If you have error page defined in web application be sure to put the path above that otherwise it will always trigger the error page.

Filename: app-routing.module.ts

[image]